# PHP SQL insert prepared statements doesn't insert properly

Tags: php, sql, statements

When executing the following code, no Errors occur but the data isn't put into the database!

```
$zero = 0;
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "andrewle_me", "*****", "andrewle_velocity");
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts Values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("issssssi", $zero, $_POST["username"], password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT), $_POST["Email"], $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["lastname"], $_POST["nationality"], $zero);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $connection->close();
    echo "Success";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your posts and password hash outside of the param binding. Set the fields in the table that your values are going to be entered into.